# How can I implement ImageMagick or other image processing to files that are being uploaded directly to S3 without passing through my server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, amazon-s3, imagemagick, jquery-file-upload

I am developing a website in which a user can upload a picture. I have implemented a direct-to-Amazon S3 uploader that allows the image to be uploaded directly to my S3, without being uploaded to my server first.

My problem is that I would like to a) resize the image to 300x80 and b) run some validations such as file size limit and file type, but I can't do that since the file never passes my server.

I am guessing there is a way to do the validations on the file before it is uploaded. But is there a way for me to resize a file even though it never goes through my server? Or, should I just give up on the direct upload in this case, since it's pretty small files, and just use Paperclip?

Here is my upload code for reference:

```
$('.imageUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) {
        var fileInput    = $(elem);
        var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
        var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
        var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
        var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
        fileInput.after(barContainer);
        fileInput.fileupload({
          fileInput:       fileInput,
          formData:        <%=s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>,
          url:             '<%=s3_direct_post.url %>',
          type:            'POST',
          autoUpload:       true,
          paramName:        'file',
          dataType:         'XML',
          replaceFileInput: false,
          progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
          },
          start: function (e) {
            submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

            progressBar.
              css('background', 'green').
              css('display', 'block').
              css('width', '0%').
              text("Loading...");
          },
          done: function(e, data) {
            submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
            progressBar.text("Uploading done");

            var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
            var url   = '//<%= URI.parse(s3_direct_post.url).host %>/' + key;

            var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
            form.append(input);

            fileInput.removeAttr('name')
          },
          fail: function(e, data) {
            submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
            console.log(e);
            console.log(data);
            progressBar.
              css("background", "red").
              text("Failed");

            var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: '' })
            form.append(input);

            fileInput.removeAttr('name')
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: I believe AWS offers [lambda service](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) for this.

Comment: I believe you can check file size and type with JavaScript in the users browser before upload but it is not very secure. I would also say you need to do more than just check file size and type if accepting user uploads.